# DRF: Unable to make authenticated calls with token in header

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a list view that is authenticated but whenever I try to make a request with the token in the header, I get a 400 error. Any ideas?

list view

```
class EventListView(ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = EventFilterSerializer
    ...
```

get auth token endpoint:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),
]
```

settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Postman Screenshot

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: Where is that token coming from? The `IsAuthenticated` permission checks to see if the user is logged in, this is usually done with a session cookie

Comment: @IainShelvington I updated the post to include the get_auth endpoint

Comment: You've set `authentication_classes` to an empty tuple on your view, could that be this issue? You need to add `TokenAuthentication` or remove that line if it is in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`

Comment: I do have the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` configured in settings. I also included the class in the view but I'm still getting the 400. I updated the post again.

Comment: I stand corrected, that fixed my issue, I had to restart the server to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Iain Shelvington, even though I had DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES permissions configured in settings, I overrode it in the view. By removing the empty `authentication_classes` tuple entirely or adding TokenAuthTokenAuthenticationen, my issue was resolved.